# Status of accessing the current offset of a consumer?

Tags: spring-kafka

I see that there was some discussion on this subject before[*], but I cannot see any way how to access this. Is it possible yet?

Reasoning: we have for example ContainerStoppingErrorHandler. It would be vital, if container was automatically stopped, to know, *where* it stopped. I guess ContainerStoppingErrorHandler could be improved to log partition/offset, as it has access to Consumer (I hope I'm not mistaken). But if I'm stopping/pausing it manually via MessageListenerContainer, I cannot see a way how to get info about last processed offset. Is there a way?

[*] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/431

Comment: Can you explain why you need to capture the current offset when the container is stopped? The offset is maintained within Kafka and will be used when the container is started again. Kafka provides command line tools to determine the current offfsets for a consumer group, or you can get it programmatically, if you need it for some reason. That said, I have [created an issue to support it](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/issues/867).

Comment: I'm new to kafka, I do not have production experience, I'm just guessing what I could potentially need in production. So maybe I'm trying to do something in not correct way, but it's hard to get answers to this questions. So, what do I need it for? Something failed, consumer is stopped, and some team complains, that only subset of his data was consumed. Messages could contain information like timestamp or ID I can use to track what was the last consumed record. I did not know, that it can be obtained from cli, but having that in app logs could be nicer. Thanks for RFE.

Comment: and for completeness: that cli is: "./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group testGroup --describe" Took me a while to find what should be passed as parameters and what not, since command docummentation isn't very helpfull. Maybe it will help some reader in future.